# Track progress Flutter video player

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi I'm using the flutter video player plugin, I have something similar like this `[{phrase:"something", startAt: 1039}, {phrase:"other somthing", startAt: 26500}]` is there a way to change in ui the phrase based on the start time while the video is playing.

I have try to use a timer with a duration of 100 ms but I retrieve no exact time from the Flutter video player plugin.

Answer (score 11):

You probably want to take a look at [stateful widgets](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/#creating-stateful-widget) as they allow you to do exactly this. In short, you can set `phrase` to be some variable and once the video starts you can call `setState` and change the variable. Flutter will automatically redraw the widget and the text will be updated.

To determine if the video player is playing you can add a listener to your video controller.

```
_controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4',
    )
      ..addListener(() {
        final bool isPlaying = _controller.value.isPlaying;
        if (isPlaying != _isPlaying) {
          setState(() {
            _isPlaying = isPlaying;
          });
        }
      })
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
```